# como hago para agrupar este array en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    tengo esto:
[
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"]
]

quiero esto:

[
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"]
]
```

Alguna función?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["preegunta 1", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta 2", "estudio 2", "proyecto 2"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"],
    ["pregunta3", "estudio 1", "proyecto 1"]
];

var temp = '';
var otroArr = [];
arr.forEach( function(a){
  if( temp != a.join() ){
    otroArr.push( a );
    temp = a.join();
  }
});

console.log( otroArr );
```

Se me ocurre ciclar el arreglo y convertirlo a cadena, luego comparar la iteración actual con la que se guardó y así sacar los duplicados.

Quizá haya mejores formas, pero esa se me ocurre de prima instancia.

Comment: de igual forma funciona, gracias!